# ks.test e p-value < 2.2e-16

Tags: r

Estou tentando comparar duas distribuições, porém quando vou aplicar o ks.test para as duas, só obtendo o valor do 'D' e o p-value coincidentemente dá o mesmo valor para as duas, '< 2.2e-16'.
Tive a ideia de retirar os valores iguais a zero para ver o resultado, e o ks.test apresentou todos os valores adequadamente. Só que infelizmente, para essa análise, eu tenho que deixar também os valores iguais a zero.

Alguém já teve esse problema? Ou alguma ideia de como proceder? 
Eu preciso ter algum valor para p-value, para poder aceitar ou rejeitar a hipótese nula.

---

Meus dados são extensos, por isso não tinha colocado aqui. Segue abaixo:

```
d<-c(4.1,3.7,11.1,15.0,5.1,12.3,0.1,0.2,0.0,0.4,0.0,23.2,0.0,0.0,13.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,18.6,3.3,0.2,4.2,0.1,0.0,0.7,11.6,1.0,28.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.3,10.5,9.7,1.7,0.0,0.5,0.0,1.9,16.7,26.4,9.2,1.2,1.4,9.0,35.3,8.6,0.6,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.5,2.9,27.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,15.4,0.0,0.0,5.3,1.3,2.1,0.3,22.1,0.0,0.0,5.7,4.2,68.5,1.7,8.7,0.0,9.6,0.0,15.6,0.0,1.9,14.8,0.1,2.4,0.0,0.0,1.1,22.0,1.8,39.4,0.0,0.1,29.5,14.0,0.0,4.5,0.0,37.2,0.0,0.0,21.6,0.0,21.6,1.3,24.5,1.9,1.8,14.1,12.1,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.2,15.4,1.2,0.4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,18.9,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.6,17.2,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.7,21.2,35.7,0.0,0.0,.8,1.7,10.4,0.0,4.9,0.0,0.9,0.6,6.2,2.2,0.0,0.7,7.6,0.1,1.8,29.4,5.4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,34.4,0.6,11.2,0.0,0.6,1.7,0.3,0.0,8.4,2.6,0.2,27.6,2.6,0.4,0.0,18.5,0.0,25.5,0.9,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.0,1.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.3,0.0,0.0,1.1,0.0,0.9,0.8,1.2,2.6,0.0,6.6,0.0,0.8,15.1,2.6,2.1,4.0,2.2,0.0,15.5,15.0,0.1,1.9,12.8,31.6,0.0,0.0,0.0,25.9,0.0,0.0,1.3,0.0,0.3,0.0,0.0,0.1,0.0,0.1,10.9,1.3,0.0,0.0,1.8,4.4,0.0,2.1,20.2,0.0,12.5,0.1,0.0,0.7,0.0,4.0,46.8,27.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,16.9,0.0,23.7,29.8,0.0,0.0,5.5,0.0,23.8,0.0,0.1,4.4,0.1,43.2,15.4,9.5,0.9,0.0,1.2,7.0,15.9,0.0,9.9,3.5,12.0,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.1,1.1,2.6,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.4,18.4,4.5,5.2,4.1,4.3,0.0,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.0,0.0,2.2,0.0,0.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,14.5,3.1,0.0,0.0,0.1,5.7,0.5,0.1,0.2,0.0,0.0,6.8,0.0,0.2,18.3,0.0,0.2,0.0,0.0,2.5,40.9,4.4,0.0,0.0,0.8,1.0,4.5,0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.3,0.4,11.9,0.0,0.0,0.6,12.2,0.0,0.0,0.3,9.3,9.3,1.6,6.1,0.0,19.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.4,0.0,0.1,0.0,8.2,5.3,0.0,0.0,3.4,0.0,0.0,0.0,24.1,0.2,15.7,0.0,0.0,12.1,4.1,5.8,13.2,1.0,64.2,0.0,0.5,10.6,0.0,7.0,4.3,0.0,0.0,16.7,29.8,49.3,57.8,4.3,1.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,6.8,10.6,3.7,2.2,0.0,0.1,5.1,0.0,0.0,1.0,4.3,0.0,43.5,5.6,0.0,7.7,0.0,0.0,18.7,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.0,0.0,23.0,0.0,0.0,0.2,9.5,0.0,5.1,6.4,0.0,28.0,0.0,0.0,3.2,0.0,0.5,1.2,2.3,42.3,0.0,0.0,1.8,0.0,0.2,5.8,30.8,3.1,2.7)
```

A linha de raciocínio foi a seguinte:

```
n<-length(d[!is.na(d)])
media<-mean(d)
desvio<-sd(d)
vetor<- as.vector(d[!is.na(d)])
variancia<-var(vetor)*(n-1)/n
alfa<-(media)^2/(variancia)
beta<-(variancia)/(media)

ks.test(vetor,"pgamma",shape=alfa, scale=beta)
D = 0.3792, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comparando com uma normal:

```
ks.test(vetor,"pnorm",mean=media, sd=desvio)

D = 0.3002, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Testei pois queria comparar e ver com as duas distribuições, Gamma e Normal. Para que no fim conseguisse comparar os dois valores de p-value e ver qual melhor se encaixaria aos meus dados. Mas as duas seguem aparecendo p-value como: < 2.2e-16

Comment: bem vindo ao **SOpt**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para melhor perceber como funciona o site.

Comment: Iara, o Teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov (`ks.test`) compara se uma amostra segue uma determinada distribuição de probabilidade contínua ou se duas amostras seguem a mesma distribuição contínua. É um teste não-paramétrico que, para podermos rejeitar ou não a hipótese nula, temos que comparar o valor da estatística D com os valores críticos de uma tabela que dependem do tamanho da amostra e do nível de significância (ambos não informado). Apesar de que sua dúvida não pareça ser sobre a linguagem `R`, se você nos fornecer um pedaço dos seus dados, talvez possamos te ajudar de uma melhor forma.

Comment: Os resultados que obteve não são iguais, o que são é ambos menores que `2.2e-16`. Para ver porque é que o R apresenta assim, veja a página de ajuda `help(".Machine")` e printe o valor de `.Machine$double.eps`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provavelmente o que escrevi aqui não vai responder completamente a pergunta, mas o espaço de comentários é muito pequeno para o que tenho a dizer.

Não me parece correto levantar a hipótese de estes dados são normais. Veja o histograma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E é exatamente isto o que o teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov está te dizendo. Ao testar as hipóteses

```
H_0: d é gama
H_1: d não é gama
```

e

```
H_0: d é normal
H_1: d não é normal
```

tu rejeita ambas as hipóteses nulas. Ou seja, teus dados não são gama com alfa e beta, nem normais com media e desvio. Portanto, nada de errado aqui.

O problema agora é descobrir qual é a distribuição dos teus dados. Note que a barra referente ao zero no histograma é muito alta. Ao perceber isso, rodei

```
table(d > 0)
FALSE  TRUE 
  171   280
```

que serve para contar quantos zeros e quantos não-zeros há no conjunto de dados. No caso, temos 171 zeros e 280 valores diferentes de zero. Isso tem cara de uma mistura de distribuições, onde uma distribuição é responsável pelas medidas positivas e outra apenas pelos zeros.

Outra ideia que podemos testar é encontrar alguma distribuição pros dados a partir do pacote `fitdistrplus`:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(d, "gamma")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, 
  obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, 
  method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function 
  cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdist(d, "gamma") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
            with the error code 100
```

Veja que nem mesmo este pacote consegue encontrar parâmetros adequados para uma gama se ajustar a estes dados.

Entretanto, podemos tentar uma exponencial:

```
fitdist(d, "exp")
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate  Std. Error
rate 0.1867882 0.008795259
```

Agora sim a coisa ficou mais interessante. Ao menos a estimativa do parâmetro da exponencial convergiu. Entretanto, quando vamos plotar a densidade da exponencial em cima do histograma, o resultado não é tão legal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é tão verdade que, ao rodar o Kolmogorov-Smirnov considerando uma exponencial, novamente rejeitamos H_0:

```
ks.test(d, "pexp", 0.1867882)

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  d
D = 0.43562, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(d, "pexp", 0.1867882) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

Ou seja, estes dados também não possuem distribuição exponencial com parâmetro 0.1867882.

Portanto, tu tem duas opções aqui:

1) Vá tentando distribuições assimétricas à direita dentro com o pacote `fitdistrplus`. Se a estimação funcionar, rode o Kolmogorov-Smirnov pra confirmar se os dados tem, de fato, a distribuição encontrada.

2) Se perguntar porque tem tantos zeros no teu conjunto de dados. 171 de 451 (38%) das observações iguais a zero não é algo que se espera em geral. De onde estes dados vieram? É esperado que esta coleta tenha mesmo esta quantidade de zeros? O equipamento ou pessoa que coletou pode ter feito algo errado?

3) Trabalhar com mistura de distribuições, que aí é uma área um pouco mais complicada.

Comment: Muito obrigada Marcus Nunes. 
A parte estranha foi realmente isso, excluir as hipóteses para as duas distribuições. Mas realmente não tinha pensado no sentido de distribuições mistas. E sim, pensei no problema estar na quantidade de zeros da amostra, que faria com que o teste não ''funcionasse'', pelo menos para uma delas. 
Mas mais uma vez, muito obrigada!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar creio que está a começar de forma errada. Não deve decidir à partida que vai comparar a distribuição dos dados com tais e tais distribuições paramétricas.

Deve começar por **ver os dados**. Comece pelas estatísticas descritivas básicas dadas pela função `summary`.

```
summary(d)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#0.000   0.000   0.500   5.354   5.350  68.500
```

Isto mostra uma distribuição assimétrica, veja que o mínimo e o primeiro quartil são iguais. Outro indício disto é a diferença entre a média e a mediana. Ainda outro indício é termos a média, uma estatística muito sensível a valores extremos (*outliers*), acima do 3º quartil.
Podemos também ver que não há valores `NA`, mas como parece estar preocupada com isso, tanto que até criou o vetor `vetor` a partir do vetor `d` removendo os eventuais *missing values* `NA`, aqui vai uma maneira de verificar se existem e quantos são.

```
sum(is.na(d))
#[1] 0
```

E para ver a distribuição há o sempre utilíssimo histograma.

```
hist(d, prob = TRUE)    # Ver os dados
```

Estes dados **não são de certeza gaussianos**.
Vamos então à distibuição gama. O seu cálculo dos parâmetros estava errado, o modo certo é este.

```
media <- mean(d)
variancia <- var(d)
alfa <- media^2/variancia
beta <- media*variancia

ks.test(d, "pgamma", shape = alfa, scale = beta)
#
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  d
#D = 0.47659, p-value < 2.2e-16
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
#
#Warning message:
#In ks.test(d, "pgamma", shape = alfa, scale = beta) :
#  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

Quanto ao significado de dados repetidos e como isso afeta o teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov, veja o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232011/ties-should-not-be-present-in-one-sample-kolmgorov-smirnov-test-in-r) e o [manual da função `ks.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html):

> The presence of ties always generates a warning, since continuous
>   distributions do not generate them. If the ties arose from rounding
>   the tests may be approximately valid, but even modest amounts of
>   rounding can have a significant effect on the calculated statistic.

Em português (Google Translate + revisão minha)

> A presença de valores repetidos gera sempre um aviso, já que
>   distribuições contínuas não os permitem. Se os valores repetidos
>   surgirem do arredondamento, os testes podem ser aproximadamente
>   válidos, mas mesmo quantidades modestas de arredondamento podem ter um
>   efeito significativo na estatística calculada.

É também possível e mais natural usar a função `fitdistr` do pacote base `MASS` para calcular os valores dos parâmetros. Como os dados têm muitos zeros e essa função não aceita ajustar uma gama quando os dados têm zeros, vou somar um valor muito pequeno a cada zero.

```
vetor <- d
inx <- vetor == 0
vetor[inx] <- vetor[inx] + .Machine$double.eps^0.5

params <- MASS::fitdistr(vetor, "gamma")
```

Agora o teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

```
sh <- params$estimate["shape"]
ra <- params$estimate["rate"]

ks.test(vetor, "pgamma", shape = sh, rate = ra)
#
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  vetor
#D = 0.26847, p-value < 2.2e-16
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
#
#Warning message:
#In ks.test(vetor, "pgamma", shape = sh, rate = ra) :
#  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

Finalmente, os gráficos com as curvas das densidades calculadas acima.

```
hist(vetor, prob = TRUE)
curve(dgamma(x, shape = alfa, scale = beta), 
      from = 0, to = 70, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
curve(dgamma(x, shape = sh, rate = ra), 
      from = 0, to = 70, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Creio que deverá tentar encontrar modelos que se deem bem com tantos zeros, que assim deverá ser muito difícil encontrar uma distribuição paramétrica que se ajuste a estes dados. Apesar dos gráficos não estarem mal, ambos os testes rejeitaram a hipótese nula.

Comment: Obrigada Rui Barradas.